# Facebook link gives "This game is not available for your phone"

Tags: unity, facebook

I am developing a game in Unity and have connected to FB using the plugin.
I am able to login and send a request to another user with no problems.

However, when I click on the notification I get the message "This game is not available for your phone".

Everything is set up as it should be and both users are defined as developers for the app.

The only thing is that I have not yet published the app in FB. Is that a requirement?

Comment: I have the same issue, did you find a way to fix the problem ? Thank you

Comment: @alex Hey, welcome to [Gamedev.se]! On stack exchange sites, unlike "traditional" forums, answers are meant to answer the questions (it's not allowed to ask for further details). I have converted your question to comment, and I encourage you to keep on participating here until you get enough rep (50) to comment by yourself. You should take a look at the [help] to find out more about our model.